# Lotus Notes - button automatic delete after running formula

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

I need to create a button in Lotus Notes mail stationary which will insert a text and then the button is deleted from the message.

In the button I have:

```
res := @Prompt([OkCancelList]; "Is it OK?"; "Select result"; " ";"OK":"Failed":"");
@If(res ="OK"; 
    @Command([EditGotoField]; "Body") + @Command([EditInsertText]; "Everything is fine); 
    @Command([EditGotoField]; "Body") + @Command([EditInsertText]; "Not so good mate"));
```

This part works fine, but I am not sure how to delete the button after click. Usually works `@Command([EditClear])` but not in this case when I use `@Command([EditGoToField])` in the formula.

I suppose i need to use GoToField again with the correct button identifier and then run EditClear, but I do not know where to find it, or if there is another way to do it... Ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the button in field Body and nothing else that have to remain
 then change your code to:

```
@Command([EditGotoField]; "Body");
@Command([EditSelectAll]);
res := @Prompt([OkCancelList]; "Is it OK?"; "Select result"; " ";"OK":"Failed":"");
@If(res ="OK"; 
     @Command([EditInsertText]; "Everything is fine"); 
    @Command([EditInsertText]; "Not so good mate"));
```

It selects the content of Body (including button) and replaces it by the new text.

Comment: Which in theory should work and the SelectAll indeed selects everything in the message, but then only the text is inserted in beginning and button remains in there, nothing is overwritten.

Comment: It works not just in theory :) - did you test it with just my code? I created a new mail, created a button with this code in Body field, added some other text and clicked on button. It remains just the text inserted by button and nothing else.

Comment: yes you were right, i probably made a mistake somewhere, it works now, thank you.

Is there a way how to overwrite/delete only the button? Or how to select only specified number of lines in body?

Comment: Only with sendkeys(). But the sendkeys() implementation in LotusScript doesn't work. You would have to use Windows' sendkey(). But, that's a pain and probably not worth the effort in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your document is (or could be put into) edit mode, you could still have the button, but have the button in it's own paragraph (or table cell) with a hide-when formula of of `MySpecialButtonPressed!=""`, and then include the line

```
FIELD MySpecialButtonPressed := @Now;
```

in the button code.

(Edit: changed test from `=1` to `!=""`, then changed the set value from `1` to `@Now` because Notes doesn't store Boolean values. Unless you're sending out millions of these, the cost of using dates instead of numbers less than the benefit of having more specific information in case you need it.)